# Regex for each two dash and alter string based on the match

Tags: java

I have a input as

```
String test = "this-is-name".
```

I want to check if a string follows this pattern i.e. `x-y-z` and if it follows then simply return `z`. In my example it would be `name`.

Can I get a regex for the match so that it matches exact two dash.

Comment: That doesn't look like complex task. Which part gives you trouble? To match series of non-dash symbols you can use `[^-]+`, to get specific part of regex you can use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{

    public static String parseDashes(String test) {
        Pattern exp = Pattern.compile("^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$");
        Matcher m = exp.matcher(test);
        if (m.matches())
            return m.group(3);
        else
            return null;
    }

   public static void main (String[]args) {
        String test = "this-is-name";
        System.out.println(parseDashes(test));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
name
```

I'll highlight the helpful comment made by @martinspielmann...if you wanted to require that each of x/y/z consist of at least one character, then you'd use the pattern `"^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$"` instead.

There are lots of options here depending on exactly you want to call a valid vs invalid string.  You could leave out the first two pairs of parentheses if you were not going to ever need to capture 'x' and 'y', and then you'd refer to `group(1)` instead of `group(3)`.  There's probably a fancy way of writing this more compactly taking advantage of the fact that the same pattern is used repeatedly.

NOTE: I updated my original patterns to exclude cases that return more than two dashes.

Comment: If there's at least one character needed between the dashes as I would assume from the x-y-z example, just replace the `*` by `+` signs

Comment: @Steve what about if I want 

String test = "this-is-name-to-your-place".

what I want to do is skip first two `-` and then return anything after that, so that we get the result as `name-to-your-place` . How do we change the regex for this?

Comment: "^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*)$"